# Attribute not available in search

Tags: php, module, attributes, template

I'm trying to display a custom attribute in the Productslisting.
It's working great, but when searching for products, this attribute seems to be not available here.

```
<?php
    echo $this->__('Delivery period: %s workdays', $_product->getDeliverydays());
?>
```

Why is this attribute not avaliable in search results? And what's the best way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is you attribute marked as "Used in Product Listing"?

Comment: Yes I have,,, Still not showing up...

Comment: Did you reindex and flushed cache?

Comment: Yes I did... Somehow this attribute still is not available in search... It's completely missing in the $_product array...

Comment: Did you use any custom importer such as MAGMI?

Comment: I don't think so, someone else used an import tool. But this attribute is added later. After the import.

Comment: Try this: Open one product from backend and simpy save it without modifying anything. Reindex and flush the cache. See if you have the attribute for that product.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround so that I can access the attribute.

In the foreach-loop where the products are getting listed from the collection, I called Mage::getModel('catalog/product') to get the full productmodel. Now the custom attribute is available for use.

```
$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
echo $_product->getDeliverydays()
```

I hope that someone can tell me why the custom attributes aren't available from the ProductCollection when using the search...